# Connection between Facebook aplication and iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I've been looking at the Facebook Connect for iOS, but I could not find the solution which could fulfill my requirement. I was able to create a simple log in window, user can put his/ger credentials, but when I run my iPhone app again the user has to login again.

So far I've been able to get this:

[image]

I would like to be able to get a dialog similar to this one:
[image]

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure of the answer....

But try this once.......

goto facebook.m:

- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions
       delegate:(id)delegate {

// comment the below linw and write the last line.

--------> [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];

}

Hope ur prob;em ll be solved.